# reporting and logging using androidviewclient

Tags: androidviewclient

What is **best practice** to do *logging* and *reporting* of test suite with AVC ?
I mean on running test it would be nice to get a bug report or test pass/fail report and in case of any errors like force close it would be nice to get some dump to understand the cause.

Regards,

Miten.

Comment: AVC doesn't do this. It was created for other functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Built this to distribute tests to multiple devices and collect results. Tests use AVC.
http://benhylau.github.io/yksp/